# Remote Desktop Connection - Single Sign On no Windows Server

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, single-sign-on

Good day all,

I was wondering if Single Sign On was possible in RDC, when both the client and remote computers are running on Windows 7 Enterprise; no Windows Server?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you have authentication server this won't be possible.  This can be any number of solutions that support this feature it doesn't have to be an Activate Domain server.

Comment: Supposing that I do have AD as an authentication server, are you saying that it could be possible?

Comment: I deal with absolutes; you either do or you don't; both clients would need to be connected to the same server thoigh which you say isn't the case

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have single sign-on RD session between to client operating systems (Windows 7). The minimum requirement for single sing-on is between a client machine to the windows server or windows server to server. Because, the single sign-on RD session authentication is only available in the Server operating systems, not with client operating systems. So it is not possible.

Hope this clarifies.